# Shared Monitor Objects

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Good time!

There is a big web application with lots of threads processing data back and forth. One part of it is the service that processes trades (TradeProcessingService). When a trade is received it is validated and sent for a further processing to other services. So that the TradeProcessingService is an entry point of this web app component.

Each trade is connected with exactly one exchange. As far as all the processing is based on the trade exchange, it is required to perform such processing in parallel for different exchanges.

Together with a described above functionality, there is a scheduling service (ExchangeDataUpdaterService) that updates exchange data (one by one) every 10 seconds. As far as this data is used for the trade processing, it is required to synchronize the processing and updating operations.

Thereby it is not only required to **synchronize** each **processing thread** (with all the services' method call chain) **by** an **exchange**, but also synchronize those threads with **updating threads** (also, by exchange data).

I am not experienced with such tasks. It seems that there should be some shared monitor objects (say, one per each exchange) to use in processing and updating threads...

Could you, please, suggest some best practices for dealing with the above scenario?

Comment: Sounds to me like you are looking for a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Comment: Yeah - as @OldCurmudgeon suggests, shove all the command/request objects onto one queue and have ONE consumer thread that reads them serially and operates on the data as requested. No locks except those in the blocking queue, serialised operations on the data and easy to debug.  Much safer/simpler than a big pile of locks.

Comment: Possibly one queue/thread per exchange e.g. a ScheduledExecutorService.

Comment: Thank you very much, guys! I'll read more about these approaches. For now leaving this question opened for more suggestions and in case of related questions after reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks OldCurmudgeon, Martin James and Peter Lawrey for the suggested solutions.
I'll describe the approach I've implemented (just an overview without any disaster recovery or resource releasing mechanisms).

As I wrote before, the main idea is to make a parallel processing for each exchange.

**Firstly**, I created a map with exchanges as keys and ExchangeTaskProcessorEnv classes as values, where an ExchangeTaskProcessorEnv class object contains a BlockingQueue (for the ExchangeAwareTask class objects) and an ExchangeAwareTaskProcessor class object (which is a Runnable implementer that calls an 'invoke' method of each ExchangeAwareTask class object from the queue and perform some additional processing). The described map is located in a singleton class - ExchangeTaskHolder.

**Secondly**, there is a number of operations that could be performed for different business cases: update an exchange's info, update a trade's info, synchronize data with an FTP server... For each of these cases I've created a task that extends the ExchangeAwareTask class and overrides the 'invoke' method (each task knows how it must be processed). It is worth mentioning that each task contains a reference to a corresponding exchange.

**Thirdly**, I introduced a static factory to be able to create a required task for a required exchange.

**Lastly**, when a user or a scheduling mechanism needs to perform some action it creates a required task with the factory and adds it to the ExchangeTaskHolder object that assigns it for the corresponding  exchange.

After a while I realized that there are a number of special cases when some action does not correspond any exchange or when an action corresponds all exchanges. No problem, in the first case an additional task-map-bucket could be added (***the exchange-aware processing mechanism is not affected***), while on the second case a special method of the ExchangeTaskHolder creates the required tasks for each ExchangeAwareTaskProcessor (for each exchange).

Some time later another requirement came: each task must have a certain weight. Not problem, I just changed the ExchangeTaskHolder's BlockingQueue with a PriorityBlockingQueue one.